# How to count and do jointure like stuff on couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I'm currently trying to get the number of events for one organizer.

This is what my organizer document looks like:

```
{
 "doc_type": "User",
 "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
 "blebleble: "blebleble",
}
```

This is what my event document looks like:

```
{
"doc_type": "Event",
 "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
 "blablabla: "blablabla",
}
```

I still couldn't figure out how to do some kind of jointure between both docs and do a count on the number of event that shares the same. I think I can work around the email that both docs shares but I don't know how I can do that. I'm still having trouble with CouchDB. Doesn't seems like a hard thing to do in SQL, but can't find out for nosql.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you field(s) you want to join by - email?

Comment: Yes sorry if it wasn't clear. They both share the email field with the same data, so i assumed i could kind of join them on this field for a view or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

"jointure" is not not a term I've encountered in my field so I am left to guess what is meant is *join*.

Joins are possible with CouchDB views, but what I read from the requirement in the OP is to get counts of events by email. See CouchDB's [Joins With Views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/joins.html#joins-with-views) documentation. For that, I don't see documents with an ancestral relation rather a one-to-many relation, i.e. user ==> events.

Consider this design document:

```json
{
    "_id": "_design/SO-68999682",
    "views": {
      "user_events": {
        "map": `function (doc) {             
           if(doc.doc_type === 'Event') {                         
              emit(doc.email);
           }
        }`,
        "reduce": '_count'
      }
    }
```

The view's map function simply adds `doc.email` to the 'user_events' index when appropriate.  Of particular interest the `reduce` function specifies the [built-in reduce function](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/maintenance/performance.html?highlight=reduce#built-in-reduce-functions) `_count`.

Given such a view index one may apply the [/db/_design/design-doc/_view/view-name](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#db-design-design-doc-view-view-name) endpoint to, for example,

View all events

```json
{
   reduce: false,
   include_docs: true
}
```

Get a count of all events

```json
{
   reduce: true
}
```

Get a count of events for every email (summary)

```json
{
   reduce: true,
   group_level: 1
}
```

Get a count of events for a specific email

```json
{
   reduce: true,
   group_level: 1,
   key: email
}
```

Get all events for a specific email

```json
{
   reduce: false,
   include_docs: true,
   key: email
}
```

The `_count` reduce built-in provides high performance. The snippet below demonstrates the above using the very handy and compatible [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/).

```js
async function showAllEventDocs() {
  let result = await db.query('SO-68999682/user_events', {
    reduce: false,
    include_docs: true
  });
  //show  
  gel('user_events_view').innerText = result.rows.map(row => [row.doc.email, row.doc.date].join('\t\t')).join('\n');
}

async function showEventCountTotal() {
  let result = await db.query('SO-68999682/user_events', {
    reduce: true
  });
  gel('event_count_total').innerText = result.rows[0].value;
}

async function showEventCountSummary() {
  let result = await db.query('SO-68999682/user_events', {
    reduce: true,
    group_level: 1
  });
  //show key/value (email, count)
  gel('event_count_summary').innerText = result.rows.map(row => [row.key, row.value].join('\t\t')).join('\n');
}


async function showUserEventCount(email, displayElement) {
  let result = await db.query('SO-68999682/user_events', {
    reduce: true,
    group_level: 1,
    key: email
  });
  //show value (count)
  gel(displayElement).innerText = result.rows[0].value;
}

async function showUserEvents(email, displayElement) {
  let result = await db.query('SO-68999682/user_events', {
    reduce: false,
    include_docs: true,
    key: email
  });
  //show  
  gel(displayElement).innerText = result.rows.map(row => [row.doc.email, row.doc.date].join('\t\t')).join('\n');
}

function getDocsToInstall(count) {
  const docs = [{
      "doc_type": "User",
      "email": "Jerry@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "doc_type": "User",
      "email": "Bobby@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "doc_type": "Event",
      "email": "Jerry@gmail.com",
      "date": getDocDate().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }, {
      "doc_type": "Event",
      "email": "Jerry@gmail.com",
      "date": getDocDate().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }, {
      "doc_type": "Event",
      "email": "Jerry@gmail.com",
      "date": getDocDate().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }, {
      "doc_type": "Event",
      "email": "Bobby@gmail.com",
      "date": getDocDate().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }, {
      "doc_type": "Event",
      "email": "Bobby@gmail.com",
      "date": getDocDate().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    },
  ];
  // design document
  const ddoc = {
    "_id": "_design/SO-68999682",
    "views": {
      "user_events": {
        "map": `function (doc) {             
           if(doc.doc_type === 'Event') {                         
              emit(doc.email);
           }
        }`,
        "reduce": '_count'
      }
    }
  };

  docs.push(ddoc);
  return docs;
}

const db = new PouchDB('SO-68999682', {
  adapter: 'memory'
});
// install docs and show view in various forms.
(async() => {
  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall(20)); 
  await showAllEventDocs();
  await showEventCountTotal();
  await showEventCountSummary();
  await showUserEventCount('Jerry@gmail.com', 'jerry_event_count');
  await showUserEventCount('Bobby@gmail.com', 'bobby_event_count');
  await showUserEvents('Jerry@gmail.com', 'jerry_events');
  await showUserEvents('Bobby@gmail.com', 'bobby_events');
})();
const gel = id => document.getElementById(id);

function getDocDate() {
  const today = new Date();
  const day = Math.random() * 100 % today.getDay() + 1; // keep it basic
  return new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), day)
}
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}

.plain {
  font-weight: normal
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>

<pre>All user_events (entire view)</pre>
<pre id='user_events_view'></pre>
<hr/>
<pre>Total number of events: <span id='event_count_total'></span> events</pre>
<hr/>
<pre>Event count summary (user, count)</pre>
<pre id='event_count_summary'></pre>
<hr/>
<pre>Event count by email (specific to user)</pre>
<pre>Bobby@gmail.com has <span id='bobby_event_count'></span> events</pre>
<pre>Jerry@gmail.com has <span id='jerry_event_count'></span> events</pre>
<hr/>
<pre>Events by email</pre>
<pre class="bold">Bobby@gmail.com <pre class="plain" id='bobby_events'></pre></pre>
<pre class="bold">Jerry@gmail.com <pre class="plain" id='jerry_events'></pre></pre>
<hr/>
```

Notice the demo snippet's documents have a `date` field. If such a field existed in the OPs `Event` documents, then changing the `emit` to

```js
emit(doc.email + '/' + doc.date);
```

would allow all the aforementioned queries plus the option to query by a date or date range, an exercise which I'll leave readers to explore.